# Flutter: The named parameter 'foregroundColor' isn't defined

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working through the 'Write your first Flutter app' tutorials and have gotten to part 2, step 7 without issues. However, on the line:

```
foregroundColor: Colors.black,
```

VSCode underlines `foregroundColor` and says:

```
The named parameter 'foregroundColor' isn't defined
```

It didn't change the colour after a hot reload, and it won't build with the error, the Debug Console saying:

```
lib/main.dart:17
        foregroundColor: Colors.black,
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
../…/material/theme_data.dart:219
  factory ThemeData({
          ^
```

Here is the full `build` Widget (in the `MyApp` class):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Startup Name Generator',
      theme: ThemeData(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        foregroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      home: RandomWords(),
    );
  }
```

**UPDATE**:
I didn't have

```
appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
    //themes here
),
```

inside `ThemeData`, as the tutorial showed. After adding it, it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flutter theme data do not provide the foreground attribute. But appBarThemeData provide that.
Like this

```
 theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(foregroundColor: Colors.red),

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to this codelab. https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/first-flutter-app-pt2#6

Don't worry, It's a mistake there. I already reported that one. There is no attribute named foregroundColor in the current [ThemeData class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html).

Also now flutter team suggests using ColorScheme to define colors for the application. Here is an example of the same.

```
theme: ThemeData(
  colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
    primary: Colors.blue,
    secondary: Colors.red,
    background: Colors.white,
  ),
  appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      elevation: 0,
      iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: AppColor.primaryColor)),
  scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white);
```